# How to create random string or Number in artillery load testing script?

Tags: websocket, artillery

For bombarding the server with multiple request with random data in parameters, how can I do it?

the message block in artillery script is as below,

```
    "message": 
                {

                "order1": "jngfj2434",  
                "size": "4433",
                }
```

I need to send order1 with randomstring and size in the range of 1 to 10,000 randomly.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Below code is working for me.

```
"message": 
            {

            "order1": "{{ $randomString() }}",  
            "size": "{{$randomNumber(1,10000)}}",
            }
```

Comment: You can use it when defining a variable as well:

`variables: attributeName: "Testing{{ $randomNumber(100000,999999) }}"`

Comment: god artillery's documentation is terrible.  No mention of this anywhere afaict.  It lives only in the examples folder in their github repo

Comment: Check this file in the [artillery source code](https://github.com/artilleryio/artillery/blob/d71d1ee3ff49895334121f893375a56ecaa68cd2/packages/core/lib/runner.js#L421) as it has the `$randomString` and `$randomNumber` reference.