# Artillery script for API with random number is not working

Tags: load-testing, web-api-testing, artillery

I am using random number in api call as below, but its giving error.

```
"post": {
   "url":  "https://host/abc?Id=1&Amount={{{$randomNumber(4000,40000)}}}&rate={{{$randomNumber(1000000,1200000)}}}&amountType=1"
}
```

It's giving error as

```
 { Error: Line 1: Unexpected token }
at createError (C:\Users\chintamanim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\artillery\node_modules\esprima\esprima.js:2392:21)
at unexpectedTokenError (C:\Users\chintamanim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\artillery\node_modules\esprima\esprima.js:2467:13)
at throwUnexpectedToken (C:\Users\chintamanim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\artillery\node_modules\esprima\esprima.js:2472:15)
at parsePrimaryExpression (C:\Users\chintamanim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\artillery\node_modules\esprima\esprima.js:3266:13)
at inheritCoverGrammar (C:\Users\chintamanim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\artillery\node_modules\esprima\esprima.js:2648:18)
at parseLeftHandSideExpressionAllowCall (C:\Users\chintamanim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\artillery\node_modules\esprima\esprima.js:3373:20)
at inheritCoverGrammar (C:\Users\chintamanim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\artillery\node_modules\esprima\esprima.js:2648:18)
at parsePostfixExpression (C:\Users\chintamanim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\artillery\node_modules\esprima\esprima.js:3449:16)
at parseUnaryExpression (C:\Users\chintamanim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\artillery\node_modules\esprima\esprima.js:3509:20)
at inheritCoverGrammar (C:\Users\chintamanim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\artillery\node_modules\esprima\esprima.js:2648:18)
 index: 29,
 lineNumber: 1,
 column: 30,
 description: 'Unexpected token }' }
 Unexpected error, Artillery shutting down.
```

Comment: Seems like they aren't going to fix it... https://github.com/shoreditch-ops/artillery/issues/87

Answer (score 0):

Now is working.
It can be used like this
"{{ $randomNumber(1,3) }}" or $randomNumber(1,3)

reference:
[How to create random string or Number in artillery load testing script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096569/how-to-create-random-string-or-number-in-artillery-load-testing-script)